# Vue js not able to get config value

Tags: javascript, vue.js

`console.log(process.env.test);` prints undefined.

I have below config in my dev.env.js file. 
Is there anything I am missing?

```
'use strict'
const merge = require('webpack-merge')
const prodEnv = require('./prod.env')

module.exports = merge(prodEnv, {
  NODE_ENV: '"development"',
  TEST: '"http://localhost/api"'
})
```

Comment: are you sure the file path './prod.env' is correct?

Comment: In which file do you try to log it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the latest VueJS, you should prefix your ENV variables with `VUE_APP_`. See [the documentation](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html).

```
'use strict'
const merge = require('webpack-merge')
const prodEnv = require('./prod.env')

module.exports = merge(prodEnv, {
  NODE_ENV: '"development"',
  VUE_APP_TEST: '"http://localhost/api"'
})
```

Also, note that `NODE_ENV` and `BASE_URL` are the two exceptions for this rule.